# Removing elements from a list of a list

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have the data below, which is a list of lists.  I would like to remove the last two elements from each list, leaving only the first three elements.  I have tried `list.append()`, `list.pop()` but can't seem to get them to work.  I guess it is not possible to remove elements from a list in a for loop, which is what I had been previously trying.  What is the best way to go about this?

```
data = [(datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 12, 19, 24, 50), u'78:E4:00:0C:50:DF', u' 8', u'Hon Hai Precision In', u''), (datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 12, 19, 24, 50), u'78:E4:00:0C:50:DF', u' 8', u'Hon Hai Precision In', u''), (datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 12, 19, 24, 48), u'9C:2A:70:69:81:42', u' 5', u'Hon Hai Precision In 12:', u''), (datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 12, 19, 24, 47), u'00:1E:4C:03:C0:66', u' 9', u'Hon Hai Precision In', u''), (datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 12, 19, 24, 47), u'20:C9:D0:C6:8F:15', u' 8', u'Apple', u''), (datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 12, 19, 24, 47), u'68:5D:43:90:C8:0B', u' 11', u'Intel Orate', u' MADEGOODS'), (datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 12, 19, 24, 47), u'68:96:7B:C1:76:90', u' 15', u'Apple', u''), (datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 12, 19, 24, 47), u'68:96:7B:C1:76:90', u' 15', u'Apple', u''), (datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 12, 19, 24, 47), u'04:F7:E4:A0:E1:F8', u' 32', u'Apple', u''), (datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 12, 19, 24, 47), u'04:F7:E4:A0:E1:F8', u' 32', u'Apple', u'')]
```

Comment: Actually you don't have a list of lists, you have a list of tuples

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension and create a new list of lists with 2 elements removed from each sublist

```
data = [x[:-2] for x in data]
```

Comment: awesome! thank you.  i knew it was simpler than what i had been trying!

Comment: Why not just `data = [x[:-2] for x in data]`?

Comment: @iCodez, done. I wrote it out in 2 steps for the sake of elaboration but I guess it just makes me look like a dummy ;-)

Answer (score 2):

As @christian says, you have a list of `tuple`, as opposed to `list`. The distinction is significant here as `tuple` is immutable. You can convert to `list` of `list` like this

```
data = map(list, data)
```

Now you can mutate each item as you iterate over it

```
for item in data:
     del item[-2:]
```

In your case the list comprehension is better because it works on your `list` of `tuple` equally well.

Comment: just curious on the indicators or how i was supposed to know that i had a list of tuples as opposed to a list of a list??

Comment: @Barnaby, `[1,2,3]` is a `list`. `(1,2,3)` is a `tuple`