# Looping through list of tuples to post each one within a function

Tags: python, function, post, for-loop, google-analytics

So, my first two functions, `sqlPull()` and `dupCatch()` work perfectly, but when I try to pass `new_data` (the unique MySQL tuple rows) to the `post()` function, nothing happens.  I am not getting errors, and it continues to run.  Normally if I were to execute a static post request I would see it instantaneously in `Google Analytics`, but nothing is appearing, so I know something is wrong with the function. I assume the error lies in the for loop within the `post()` function, but I am not sure what about it.  Maybe I can't unpack the variables like I am currently doing because of what I did to them in the previous function?

```
import mysql.connector
import datetime
import requests
import time


def sqlPull():
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(user='xxxxx', password='xxxxx', host='xxxxx', database='MeshliumDB')
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT TimeStamp, MAC, RSSI FROM wifiscan ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC LIMIT 20;")
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    connection.close()
    time.sleep(5)
    return data

seen = set()
def dupCatch():
    data = sqlPull()
    new_data = []
    for (TimeStamp, MAC, RSSI) in data:
        if (TimeStamp, MAC, RSSI) not in seen:
            seen.add((TimeStamp, MAC, RSSI))
            new_data.append((TimeStamp, MAC, RSSI))      
    return new_data

def post():
    new_data = dupCatch()
    for (TimeStamp, MAC, RSSI) in new_data:
        requests.post("http://www.google-analytics.com/collect", 
            data="v=1&tid=UA-22560594-2&cid={}&t=event&ec={}&ea=InStore&el=RSSI&ev={}&pv=SipNSiz_Store".format(
              MAC,
              RSSI,
              TimeStamp)
            )

while run is True:
    sqlPull()
    dupCatch()
    post()
```

Comment: For future reference, it would help to link your question to previous questions about the same code, like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19991899/function-to-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-of-tuples-in-python), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19991087/python-if-statement-to-match-lists-of-tuples-removing-duplicates), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19944770/looping-through-a-list-of-tuples-to-make-a-post-request-with-each-tuple), and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19944376/removing-elements-from-a-list-of-a-list).

Comment: This means people who want to know the background (what's the higher-level thing you're trying to do, to make sure this isn't an [XY question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and we're answering the right thing) can see it. It also makes it obvious that you're doing the hard work yourself, and only coming to SO when you get stuck somewhere, which people will appreciate.

Comment: thank you for the advice. in your opinion am i asking too many questions about the same code? i really am trying to do this on my own , but testing with easier scenarios in this function is not giving the  right results.

Comment: I don't think you are asking too many questions. However, it might _look_ that way to someone who vaguely recognized the question and said "Didn't we already fix this for him two days ago?" A link to the question makes it clear that we _didn't_ already fix this for you two days ago; we fixed an earlier problem, you made more progress after that, and you got stuck again.

Comment: Can you try putting a print in the `post` loop (ideally, `data="v=1&…".format("…")`, then `print(data)`, then `requests.post(url, data=data)`, so we can be sure that requests is getting exactly the right string)?

Comment: Meanwhile, instead of trying to form-encode the data manually, just pass a `dict` to [`requests.post`](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests), and let it do the hard work (which you may have gotten wrong somewhere) for you.

Comment: Also, if `post` a dict, `requests` will automatically set the `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` header for you. I don't know if GA requires this (it might just assume that if there's no content type the default is form encoded), but it _might_.

Comment: currently, broke everything..trying to fix

Answer (score 0):

Your `post` function calls `dupCatch()`. But you also call `dupCatch` in your main run loop, right before calling `dupCatch`.

Similarly, your `dupCatch` function calls `sqlPull()`, but you also call `sqlPull` in your main run loop.

Those extra calls mean you end up throwing away 2 batches of data for each batch you process.

You could restructure your code so your functions take their values as arguments, like this:

```
while run is True:
    data = sqlPull()
    newdata = dupCatch(data)
    post(newdata)
```

… and then change `dupCatch` and `post` so they use those arguments, instead of calling the functions themselves.

Alternatively, you could just remove the extra calls in the main run loop.

Comment: hi i have fixed this part actually, i think the problem lies in unpacking the for loop in post()